# Laptop internal drive ejection

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop

I've installed a secondary 750 GB WD Scorpio drive in my Thinkpad laptop and it was working fine for a while until recently when every time I wake from sleep there is a dialog box which pops up to inform me that the internal drive did not eject properly. This often crashes my Win 7 laptop and I've tried to troubleshoot it myself but with no avail. Sometimes even when the laptop is running, the internal drive will pop up as autodetected (which is what happens when USB drives are plugged in for example).

Comment: Can you add some more details ?

Comment: What details would be helpful?

Comment: Provide some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem before. One of these steps may help you

- Movement of the laptop has made the connection unstable

  - Please open the laptop up and check the conenction, remove it and put it back in
- Your drive is encrypted

  - Encryption software can be tricky when it comes to hibernation and standby
  - Unmount the drive before going to standby or set it so it doesn't fore-eject on standby
- Your drive is damaged

  - Your device may have a problem on a hardware level
  - Please put it into an HDD-adapter and connect it to another computer or
  - Put it directly into another computer and see if the error occurs there
  - A damaged drive may act like this when the reader happens upon a damaged block or part of the HDD or the reader itself or the contacts are broken.

Comment: One advice for the first suggestion ("open the laptop up"): Have a look at the [Lenovo support site](http://support.lenovo.com/), there you'll find the maintenance manual for your laptop, which explains how to disassemble in a very comprehensible way.  You may also find them linked at the [ThinkWiki](http://thinkwiki.org/) side to your specific model (I'll find it lots easier to get them there).

Comment: I already tried these steps and even used a HDD dock to test the hard drive, which works. I can't test it in another computer because I don't have one. I don't have any encryption software. I feel this is more of a software issue than hardware because this problem cropped up recently and the hard drive has been working well for a long time. The HD is still working well but has this annoying tendency I described.